# a subquery within a subquery - is it possible?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have this sql below that i use to compare values of z. I put z in a subquery and then compare it.

My qn is in in my else statement below, i want to put in another formula to calculate something else of which the info is only available in another table called var1(for example, n). i would like to put in sum(n)/count(n) to end as cv in my else statement. and then make a case statement if the cv > 10 then too large, if < 10 too little.

am i supposed to do another subquery in this subquery? any advise pls. thanks!

```
select 
z, 
CASE 
when z > 1 then 'Pls increase your inputs' 
when z < -1 then 'Pls decrease your inputs'
else 'No comment' END as Input

from 

(select
    case
    when S < 0 then (S/En-Eg))
    else (S/En+Eg)) 
    end as z
from var2);
```

Comment: Please specify the flavor of SQL that you are trying to use.

Comment: And a sample table definiton, with sample output you'd expect?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. what do you mean by flavor of SQL? 

table definition for table var2
S integer
En float
Eg float

table deft for var1
n integer



sample output would be :- 

Z-Condition              Comments        
------------------------------------------------
>1                      'Pls increase your inputs'
<-1                     'Pls decrease your inputs'
<1 & >-1                 If sum(n)/count(n) > 10 then 'LARGE'
                         Else 'SMALL'


Please let me know if you need any other information?

Comment: @rayhan: "Flavor of SQL" means what SQL database (MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, DB2). Also, please edit your question to provide additional information instead of using the comments. It allows you to format correctly and makes it easier for others to see as well.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. For aggregates like SUM() and COUNT(), I suggest using a correlated subquery; that is, the subquery is guaranteed to return one aggregate value (SUM(n)/COUNT(n)) for each key value (var1.primary_key).

For example, this query uses a correlated subquery to return the value you desire, making SUM(n)/COUNT(n) available to the outer query:

```
SELECT      v.z,
            CASE WHEN v.z > 1
                 THEN 'Pls increase your inputs'
                 WHEN v.z < -1
                 THEN 'Pls decrease your inputs'
                 ELSE 'No comment' END AS INPUT,
            CASE WHEN v.cv > 10
                 THEN 'Pls decrease your inputs'
                 WHEN v.cv < 10
                 THEN 'Pls increase your inputs'
                 ELSE 'No comment' END AS INPUT                     
  FROM      (SELECT      CASE WHEN s < 0
                              THEN (s / en - eg)
                              ELSE (S/En+Eg) END AS 'z',
                         ISNULL(AVG_N.cv, 0) AS 'cv'
               FROM      var2
                         INNER JOIN 
                         (
                          SELECT      var1.primary_key AS 'PrimaryKey',
                                      SUM(var1.N) / COUNT(var1.N) AS 'cv'
                            FROM      var1
                           WHERE      var1.primary_key = var2.primary_key
                          GROUP BY    var1.N
                         ) AVG_N
                         ON AVG_N.PrimaryKey = var2.primary_key
            ) v
```